# C# substring parse using regular expression (ATL >> NET)?

Tags: c#, regex, atl

What is the C# & .NET Regex Pattern that I need to use to get "bar" out of this url?

> ```
> http://www.foo.com/bar/123/abc
> ```

In ATL regular expressions, the pattern would have been

> ```
> http://www\.foo\.com/{[a-z]+}/123/abc
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution that breaks the url up into component parts; protocol, site and part. The protocol group is not required so you could give the expression 'www.foo.com/bar/123/abc'. The part group can contain multiple sub groups representing the folders and file under the site.

```
^(?<protocol>.+://)?(?<site>[^/]+)/(?:(?<part>[^/]+)/?)*$
```

You would use the expression as follows to get 'foo'

```
string s = Regex.Match(@"http://www.foo.com/bar/123/abc", @"^(?<protocol>.+://)?(?<site>[^/]+)/(?:(?<part>[^/]+)/?)*$").Groups["part"].Captures[0].Value;
```

The breakdown of the expression results are as follows

protocol: http://
site: www.foo.com
part[0]: bar
part[1]: 123
part[2]: abc

Answer (score 3):

Simply:
#http://www\.foo\.com/([a-z]+)/123/abc#

use parenthesis instead of brackets.

You will need to use a character on the front and the end of the regular expression to make it work too.

Comment: actually this is wrong because the "." is considered any char?  So yours also evaluates fine for http://wwwxfood.com/bar/123/abc

Comment: # is not a valid character in ASP.NET,  I think you mean ^ and $

Comment: Also it wasn't escaped when I posted the comment.

Comment: @Nick Actually it was excaped but for some reason you have to double escape your text on SO ^_^ , as for the #s don't you need a delimiter usually for your REGEX ... ?

Answer (score 2):

Pretty much the same thing

```
    http://www\.foo\.com/([a-z]+)/123/abc
```

Answer (score 2):

This will almost work - just a tiny modification - change brackets to parenthesis.

```
http://www\.foo\.com/([a-z]+)/123/abc
```

But I consider this regex of not much use because it includes almost the whole string. Would it not be better to match the first path element independently from the whole rest?

```
^http://[^/]*/([^/]*).*$
```

Comment: Ignore the semicolon, SO added it for some reason.